# How can I delete the automatic Indexes in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

So I have a live Python application on App Engine that has far too many automatic indexes. I noticed a high amount of datastore writes for my low entity count and I believe this is the cause. Each entity has many StringProperties and some even have StringListProperties.

I added the indexed = False to all my object's properties (I don't every use a query where this would matter):

`someproperty = db.StringProperty(indexed = False)`

Is there anything else I need to do for *new* entities to be unindexed? Do I need to increment the app's version id?

Do I need to run `appcfg.py vacuum_indexes .` ?

Comment: You might want to review your data model and your controller if you get unwanted indexes. If you have the best structure in your code then you could avoid that the problem appears.

Comment: @Nicke I agree with you and that is the long term goal. This is simply something I can do very easily for a decent short term improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vacuum_indexes is only for indexes defined in index.yaml, for automatic index its enough to set indexed = False and uploaded a new version.

You can see the impact of setting indexed to False in the development server datastore page in the write counts column.

Comment: I've seen great improvement on my production server (looking at `Datastore Index Write Ops`) but where is this located on the development server? The closest thing I found was `Datastore Statistics` but that isn't too helpful

Comment: For reasons beyond my understanding the GAE team decided that only the dev server will show this value.

Comment: But thats what I'm asking. I *don't* see this on the dev server (as in my local machine), only production (as in the google hosted environment)

Comment: @smith324 where in the production server do you see: "Datastore Index Write Op"?

Comment: Its on the Quota Details page. I think its new since App Engine left preview, I don't remember it before that.

Comment: @smith324 this is the total number of write and its not available in the dev server, you can see per entity writes in the dev server data store page look for "write op" column for each entity displayed.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the existing automatic indices you will have to retrieve every single entity and re-put it with the `indexed = False` properties.

If you don't do this, then the automatic indices will stick around.  However, the new entities you create will not be added to those indices.

Comment: But is there any reason to go through that effort to get rid of the old index now that you are not using it? It seems like you should be able to just leave it alone unless it is using a huge amount of space you need to recover.

Comment: I think storage space is the only thing you pay for in the case of an out-dated index lying around.